# Livewire component not updating after model delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Being new to Livewire (3) but charmed by its capabilities I'm giving it a try. I'm follwing the Livewire v3 basic screencasts and changed the todo to a projects feature. When I delete a project I expect the component to update and not show the deleted project anymore, but somehow it's not happening. (Un)archiving works like a charm. This is in a child component, not sure if that matters. Obviously I'm overlooking something but don't yet see what it is. Below I lay out my set up.

I have a ProjectsOverview component, that has multiple ProjectCard components in it, like so:

## projects.blade.php

```
<livewire:projects-overview :$projects />
```

## projects-overview.blade.php

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8">
    @foreach($projects as $project)
    <livewire:project-card wire:key="{{ $project->id }}" :$project />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

## project-card.blade.php

```
<div class="h-48 @if($project->is_archived) !text-gray-400 @endif bg-gray-50 shadow-lg px-4 py-2 rounded-md">
    <h4 class="mb-2 -mx-4 px-3 border-l-4 @if($project->is_archived)border-l-gray-400 @else border-l-red-600 @endif py-2 font-black">{{ $project->title }}</h4>
    <div class="h-20">
        <p>{{ $project->description }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="border-t border-grey-300 -mx-4 px-3 pt-3 mt-4 text-gray-400 text-xs flex justify-between">
        <div>
            @if(!$project->is_archived)
            <button wire:click="archive({{ $project->id }})" class="hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-600 p-1 rounded-md">@svg('phosphor-archive', 'w-4 inline-block') archive</button>
            @else
            <button wire:click="unarchive({{ $project->id }})" class="hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-600 p-1 rounded-md">@svg('phosphor-archive', 'w-4 inline-block') unarchive</button>
            @endif

            <button wire:click="$parent.delete({{ $project->id }})" class="hover:bg-red-200 hover:text-red-600 p-1 rounded-md">@svg('phosphor-trash', 'w-4 inline-block') delete</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if(!$project->is_archived)
            <a wire:navigate href="{{ $project->path() }}" class="hover:bg-blue-800 text-white font-bold bg-blue-600 p-1 rounded-md">@svg('phosphor-folder-open', 'w-4 inline-block') open</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The archiving / unarchiving is working like a charm, deleting a project is the issue.

While the delete succeeds, the <livewire:projects-overview :$projects/> is not reflecting the missing eloquent model that has been deleted. When I manually refresh the page it is gone.

## ProjectsOverview component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Project;
use Livewire\Component;

class ProjectsOverview extends Component
{
    public $projects;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->projects = auth()->user()->projects;
    }

    public function delete(Project $project)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->projects->contains($project)) {
            $project->delete();
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        // tried to reload upon each render... doesn't help
        //$this->projects = auth()->user()->projects;

        return view('livewire.projects-overview');
    }
}
```

I've tried to call $this->mount() in combination with $this->render() inside the delete() method, but to no avail.

Even more so, the listed projects are by default sorted descending by their updated_at attribute. When the delete button is clicked the ordering of all projects in the overview is changed, but the missing one is put to the last place. Is it some sort of caching? Async thingy? Not updating a variable properly?

What am I overlooking?

Comment: When you logically delete a row, the deleted_at column is filled and I presume that the updated_ at column is also updated.
If the relation *projects* in the User model contains *->withTrashed()*, you get also the logically deleted rows in the list